# How can change the color of the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, color

What is the best way to change the color of the entire table of contents. I saw a lot of tutorials but it's complicated for me (I am a beginner).

Comment: Very simply: load the `xcolor` package (with options `svgnames` and `x11names`, if your want to call colours by their names rather than their rgb or cmyk codes) and write in the body of your document: `{\color{your_best_loved_colour}\tableofcontents}`.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand your objective correctly, you wish to change the color that's used for all elements of the Table of Contents; these include, presumably, the title of the ToC.

To do so, you could load the `xcolor` package and insert the instruction `\color{blue}` -- or whatever color you wish to apply -- before `\tableofcontents`. To limit the scope of the `\color` instruction, encase it and the material it's supposed to apply to in a set of `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` statements.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor} %% http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\begin{document}
\begingroup % start a TeX group
\color{blue}% or whatever color you wish to use
\tableofcontents
\endgroup   % end of TeX group

\section{A}
\section{B}
\end{document}
```