# TeXworks custom dark theme - table of contents entries that are not chapter are in black when everything else is white

Tags: table-of-contents, color

I have been developing [my own custom dark theme for TeXworks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/660190/273733) that I am currently using but just recently noticed a somewhat bug with the TOC. The TOC entries for the chapter are correctly being printed in white text but the sections/subsections/etc are not. This is how the MWE is currently outputting the TOC:

[image]

I have tried adding `hyperref` with the [options suggested by Werner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/99136/273733) (namely: `\usepackage[linktoc=all]{hyperref}`) but this did not change the colour of the page numbers. The answer by [Mico to change the color of the TOC using `\begingroup`, `\endgroup`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/172590/273733) also did not work - the page numbers for sections/subsections/etc stayed black.

What am I missing that is causing this? I am not sure why the chapter numbers are displaying correctly yet the TOC entries beneath chapter are not changing to be printed in white when I have set the `\color` to white as global `\AtBeginDocument`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\AtBeginDocument{\pagecolor{black}\color{white}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First chapter}
\lipsum[1-2]
\section{Foo section}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Bar subsection}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{Second chapter}
\lipsum[1-2]
\section{Foo section}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Bar subsection}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

use

```
 \pagecolor{black}\color{white}
```

not

```
\AtBeginDocument{\pagecolor{black}\color{white}}
```

so that the default document color is white.

Comment: That is embarrassing on my part! Any idea as to why `\AtBeginDocument` changed it strictly only for those page numbers or is it just one of the TeX quirks? Thanks for the quick response, worked in my main doc and I will update my answer in the first link.

Comment: latex sets the document default color (which is set when normalising settings in page heads, floats etc to the color at `\begin{document}` but `\AtBeginDocument` is too late so you set white but the document default was black. I didn't check why only some levels are enforcing the default color

Comment: Now I know to be a little wary of `\AtBeginDocument` and look there for issues, thanks for the advice and explanation. I have updated two previous answers that contained that error so hopefully they are useful to others in the future.